# injecting form input from a post request into a get request using expressjs

Tags: javascript, express

I want to take form input from a form and inject it into a get request using expressjs. Not quite sure how to do it. I made a plnkr. I really dont want the answer just pointing in the right direction, so some sources to read would be great.

```
[enter code here][1]
```

Comment: sorry about the missing code

Comment: var express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express();
  
  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());



var name = {};

app
  .get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.jade', {name: name});
  })
  
  .post('/', function(res,req){
    // this is where i need help i think
    res.redirect('/');
  })

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question instead of creating comments, that will make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the query string to pass the data you need.

```
.post('/', function(res,req){ 
    res.redirect('/?data=' + req.body.data); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.post('/', function(rgvfbbgbvbves,req){

    req.body  // this will give you all of the relevant POST

    // this is where i need help i think 
    res.redirect('/'); 
})
```